# error with azure terraform script to create vm

Tags: azure, terraform

i have a terraform code in main.tf and outputs.tf and i have an error about key vault, this section is available on my azure dashboard :

```
module.virtual_machine.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_credentials_login: Still creating... [6m20s elapsed]
module.virtual_machine.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_credentials_password: Still creating... [6m20s elapsed]

│ Error: checking for presence of existing Secret "toto-login" (Key Vault "https://kvapplitest2sbx.vault.azure.net/"): autorest/Client#Do: Preparing request failed: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get "https://kvapplitest2sbx.vault.azure.net/secrets/toto-login/?api-version=7.4": dial tcp: lookup kvapplitest2sbx.vault.azure.net: no such host
│
│   with module.virtual_machine.azurerm_key_vault_secret.client_credentials_login,
│   on ..\..\modules\virtual_machine\14_keyvault.tf line 13, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_credentials_login":
│   13: resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_credentials_login" {
│
```

my file of terraform main.tf is :

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  alias                      = "gallery"
  subscription_id            = sort(data.azurerm_subscriptions.osfactory.subscriptions.*.subscription_id)[0]
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscriptions" "osfactory" {
  display_name_prefix = "Suez IT OSFactory"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "cloud_bundle_rg" {
  name = "rg-applitest2-sbx" # To be updated
}

module "virtual_machine" {
  source = "../../modules/virtual_machine"
  providers = {
    azurerm.gallery = azurerm.gallery
  }
  cloudbundle_info = data.azurerm_resource_group.cloud_bundle_rg
  index            = 123
  size             = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  os_disk_type     = "Standard_LRS"
  role             = "example"
  ad_domain        = "green.local"
  os = {
    type    = "Windows"
    version = "2022"
  }
}
```

my file outputs.tf is :

```
output "virtual_machine_outputs" {
  value       = module.virtual_machine
  description = "Virtual machine outputs."
}
```

can you tell me why there are an error please,

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision your requirement by overcoming the error you mentioned I was able to provision your requirement successfully by configuring the resources as expected.

The error you're encountering in your Terraform configuration seems to be related to the Azure Key Vault which indicates a problem with resolving the DNS for the Key Vault service.

The error message "no such host" typically means that the DNS name `kvapplitest2sbx.vault.azure.net` could not be resolved. This could be due to a typo in the Key Vault URL, a misconfiguration in DNS, or an issue with your network connection.

**My terraform configuration:**

**main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "cloud_bundle_rg" {
  name = "sakavya"
}

module "virtual_machine" {
  source              = "./modules/virtual_machine"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.cloud_bundle_rg.name
  key_vault_name      = "kvapplitest2sbxvk"
  vm_size             = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@ssword1234!"  # Please use a secure method to handle passwords
}
```

##### /modules/virtual_machine/main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vm_vnet" {
  name                = "vmvkVnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "East US"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "vm_subnet" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vm_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm_nic" {
  name                = "vmvkNic"
  location            = "East US"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.vm_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                = "vk-VM"
  location            = "East US"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic.id]
  size                = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  admin_username = "adminuser"
  admin_password = "Password1234!"
  disable_password_authentication = false
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = var.key_vault_name
  location            = "East US"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tenant_id           = "Your Tenent ID"
  sku_name            = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "client_credentials_login" {
  name         = "totovk-login"
  value        = "Your strong password"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

##### /modules/virtual_machine/variables.tf:

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group."
  type        = string
}

variable "key_vault_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure Key Vault."
  type        = string
}

variable "vm_size" {
  description = "The size of the Azure VM."
  type        = string
}

variable "admin_username" {
  description = "The administrator username for the VM."
  type        = string
}

variable "admin_password" {
  description = "The administrator password for the VM."
  type        = string
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]